# Is there a simpler way to check multiple values against one value in an if-statement?

Tags: java

Basically, what I want to do is check two integers against a given value, therefore, classically what you would do is something like this:

```
//just to get some values to check
int a, b;
a = (int)(Math.random()*5);
b = (int)(Math.random()*5);

//the actual thing in question
if(a == 0 || b == 0)
{
//Then do something
}
```

But is there a more concise format to do this?  Possibly similar to this (which returns a bad operand type):

```
//just to get some values to check
int a, b;
a = (int)(Math.random()*5);
b = (int)(Math.random()*5);

//the actual thing in question
if((a||b) == 0)
{
//Then do something
}
```

Comment: Why do you even want to?

Comment: because the code would look better then?

Comment: As a way to make if statements that have lots of variables checking against the same variable become more concise.

Comment: @grapeot: It's the same thing; substitute `0` for `x`, and `a` and `b` for the integer literals.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such construct in Java.

It this kind of comparison is frequent in your code, you can implement a small function that will perform the check for you:

```
public boolean oneOfEquals(int a, int b, int expected) {
    return (a == expected) || (b == expected);
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
if(oneOfEquals(a, b, 0)) {
    // ...
}
```

If you don't want to restrict yourselft to integers, you can make the above function generic:

```
public <T> boolean oneOfEquals(T a, T b, T expected) {
    return a.equals(expected) || b.equals(expected);
}
```

Note that in this case Java runtime will perform *automatic boxing and unboxing* for primitive types (like `int`), which is a performance loss.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I have three variables, or four, or a larger amount that for some reason aren't in an array?  I'd have to rewrite this function each time to adjust to the different number of inputs.

Comment: Not exactly, you can use variable length parameter list: `public <T> boolean oneOfEquals(T expected, T... actual) { ... }` and a for-loop in the body of the function. I'll show you an example if you'd like to @Amndeep7.

Comment: It seems simple enough to grasp, one question though, what does T... actual become?  Is it a list of some sort or an array or what?

Comment: Actually it is of type `T[]`, so you can handle it like a traditional array: `for(T value : actual) { if(value.equals(expected) return true; }`

Comment: Thanks for this information.  I'd try to upvote you as well, but I still don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 47):

You can do the following in plain java

```
Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d).contains(x);
```

Answer (score 10):

[As referenced from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40623630/1079354):

> In Java 8+, you might use a `Stream` and `anyMatch`. Something like
>
> ```
> if (Stream.of(b, c, d).anyMatch(x -> x.equals(a))) {
>     // ... do something ...
> }
> ```

Note that this has the chance of running *slower* than the other if checks, due to the overhead of wrapping these elements into a stream to begin with.

Comment: It can be even shorter: `Stream.of(b, c, d).anyMatch(a::equals)`

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I think that a bit-wise OR:</strike>

```
if ((a | b) == 0) . . .
```

would work if you want to check specifically for 0. I'm not sure if this saves any execution time. More to the point, it makes for cryptic code, which will make the future maintainer of this code curse you (even if its yourself). I recommend sticking with the more-typing option.

Bah. I misread OP's original logic.

**Another go...**

If you want to test whether any one of many variables is equal to an expected value, a generic function might work:

```
public <T> boolean exists(T target, T... values) {
    for (T value : values) {
        if (target == null) {
            if (value == null) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (target.equals(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will work for any number of objects of one type. Primitives will be autoboxed so it will work with them as well. Your original code will be something like:

```
if (test(0, a, b)) {
    // do something
}
```

(A better method name would be desperately needed to even consider whether this an improvement over what you have now. Even if the test expands to 3 or 4 variables, I question the need for this kind of thing.) Note that this also works with arrays:

```
int[] values = { . . . };
if (test(0, values)) { . . .
```

and it can be used to test whether an array (or any of a collection of variables) is `null`.

Comment: But is there a way to generalize this?  As in, instead of just checking for 0, I can also compare these values to another variable, say an int named 'c'?

Comment: Doesn't work - if `a=1; b=0;`, your test fails, the original test passes.

Comment: No that's reversed, that could replace `a == 0 && b == 0`. Using bitwise and doesn't help (for two different powers of two, for example)

Comment: Might work as `!(a && b)`, but that's for the special case of zero.

Comment: Change `(a | b)` into `a * b` may solve the problem. But this won't improve efficiency, because multiply is much more expensive than bit comparison and logic operations.

Comment: @grapeot: Not necessarily.  Firstly, integer multiplication is often one cycle.  Secondly, having fewer comparisons is desirable.

Comment: @grapeot modulo power-of-two arithmetic has zero divisors, which means `a*b=0` does not imply that either `a` or `b` are zero.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth not on any processor I know. 4 or 5 cycles typically. but it may save branches which could be useful.

Comment: @harold: So the compiler optimizes `(a * b == 0)` back into `(a == 0 || b == 0)` again...?

Comment: @grapeot no.. because that would incorrect. If `a*b` happens to be zero, there are values for `a` and `b` such that neither `a` nor `b` are zero. For example `a=0x80000000 b=2`

Comment: @harold: I see. I thought Java will throw an exception here, but simple experiment proves I was wrong. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: You *can* do this with bitmath, by the way. But it isn't any shorter. Is anyone interested anyway?

Comment: @Amndeep7 - I came up with a new answer

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks for providing an example for a multiple arguments method.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(a == 0 || b == 0)
{
//Then do something
}
```

Why not keep it readable?  What is *not* concise about this?  On the other hand,

```
a = (int)(Math.random()*5);
```

involves an unnecessary cast.  Why not just use `Random` and invoke `nextInt()`?

Comment: I was never aware of that class, I had always been taught to use Math.random(), especially since that can become easily adaptable to the range of values I wish to create.

Comment: It's easy to range bound your values using Random.  For example, a random number between 1-6: 1 + myRand.nextInt(5);

Answer (score 2):

For this example, you can do

```
if (a * b == 0)
```

or for more variables

```
if (a * b * c * d == 0)
```

while more concise it may not be as clear. For larger values, you need to cast to a `long` to avoid an overflow.

Comment: You may need something larger than a long for more than two variables, if they can all be the full range..

Comment: Very true.  For larger types you need to check each one.  But for values `0 - 4` it should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the integers in a set and see if it contains the given value. [Using Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet%28E...%29):

```
if(newHashSet(a, b).contains(0)){
    // do something
}
```

But two simple int comparisons are probably easier to understand in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modification of @buc's answer that can take any number of any arguments:

```
public <T> boolean oneOfEquals(T expected, T... os) {
    for (T o : os) {
        if (expected.equals(o)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have used the bit-wise operation as Ted suggested, the expressions are not equal, since one requires at least **one** of the variables to be zero and the second requires **both** of them to be zero.

Regarding your question, there is no such shortcut in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
public static boolean match (Object ref, Object... objects)
{
    if (ref == null)
        return false;
    //
    for (Object obj : objects)
        if (obj.equals (ref))
            return true;
    //
    return false;   
}   //  match
```

So if you can check this way:

```
if (match (reference, "123", "124", "125"))
    ;   //  do something
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 we can achieve the same by using the below method:

```
private boolean methodName(int variant,int... args){
        if(args.length > 0){ return Arrays.stream(args).anyMatch( x -> x == variant); }
        return false;
    }
```

The given method will return true if the variant will match any possible input(s). This is used for or condition.

In the same way, if you want to do &&(and) condition then you just need to used other Java 8 methods:

> Note: These methods take Predicate as an argument.
>
> **anyMatch:** return true the moment the first predicate returns true otherwise false.
>
> **allMatch:** return true if all the predicates return true otherwise false.
>
> **noneMatch:** return true if none of the predicates return true otherwise false.
>
> **Performance Note:** This is good when you have enough amount of data to
>   check as it has some overhead but it works really well when you use
>   this for enough amount of data. normal way is good for just two
>   conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special syntax for that. You could make a function for that. Assuming at least Java 1.5:

```
public <T> boolean eitherOneEquals(T o1, T o2, T expectedValue) {
  return o1.equals(expectedValue) || o2.equals(expectedValue);
}

if(eitherOneEquals(o1, o2, expectedValue)) {
   // do something...
}
```